# symfony2 configuring the firewall - weird behaviour at login

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, firewall

I am using symfony2 with FOSUserBundle and i am trying to set up correctly my firewall.

I want the major part of my website to not be available to anonymous users. Home page (the $ in the public pattern) and some others should be available according to a pattern.

With my current configuration, after login I am redirected to the home page but still as anonymous. If i directly type a url of a page not allowed to anonymous directly afterwards, I can access it and I am logged (in the profiler).

My configuration:

```
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
public:
    pattern:        /(login$|register|resetting|public|$)
    anonymous:      true
main:
    pattern:        ^/
    anonymous:      false
    provider:       main
    form_login:
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
    logout:
        path:       fos_user_security_logout
        target:     /
```

What can I do to make it work properly (logged correctly after login).

EDIT:
I understand better what is happening: after login, I am being redirected to the home page=root address. This falls first into the public firewall and that's whay I'm not seen as connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Solution involves the context property of the firewall which is better described here :
[Authenticate multiple symfony2 firewalls with one login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075041/authenticate-multiple-symfony2-firewalls-with-one-login-form)

My configuration now becomes:

firewalls:

```
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
guest:
    pattern:        /(user/login$|user/register|user/resetting|$)
    anonymous:      true
    context:        main_auth
main:
    pattern:        ^/(?!user/login$)
    anonymous:      false
    provider:       main
    context:        main_auth
    form_login:
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
    logout:
        path:       fos_user_security_logout
        target:     /
    remember_me:
        key:      "%secret%"
        lifetime: 86400 # 365 jours en secondes
        path:     /
        domain:   ~ # Prend la valeur par défaut du domaine courant depuis $_SERVER
    oauth:
        remember_me: true
        resource_owners:
            facebook:           "/loginhwi/check-facebook"
            github:             "/loginhwi/check-github"
            google:             "/loginhwi/check-google"
            twitter:            "/loginhwi/check-twitter"
            linkedin:           "/loginhwi/check-linkedin"
            flickr:             "/loginhwi/check-flickr"
        login_path:        fos_user_security_login
        check_path:        fos_user_security_check
        failure_path:      fos_user_security_login
        success_handler:  foodmeup_user.handler_auth
        oauth_user_provider:
            service: fosubuser.provider
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you always can hardcode the path that you're redirected after login (in your `security.yml` file). You can read more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page)

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                default_target_path: default_security_target
```